# How do I find the MAC address of my laptop?

Tags: windows, laptop, network-adapter, mac-address

I tried to find out the MAC address in my notebook by **Run → cmd → `config /all`** but I didn't find it there.
How do I find the MAC address of my laptop?

Comment: What operating system do you have?

Comment: I usually just flip the machine over and read it off the sticker there...

Answer (score 3):

This terminal command:

```
ipconfig /all | find "Phys"
```

should return something like:

```
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 01-23-45-67-89-AB
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ipconfig /all`, try this command in cmd:

```
getmac
```

---

@bobby: I expect it's Windows as Dell's typically come with Windows, and `ipconfig /all` is a Windows command.

Answer (score 2):

You probably found it with `ipconfig /all`. It's called the "Physical Address" in the output (on an XP Dell Inspiron 2650)

Comment: pravin -- note that it's ipconfig, not just "config"

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the following is based on the assumption he's wanting to connect to a wireless network that is using a mac filter.
Since it's a notebook you most likely have both an ethernet and wireless adapter and the ipconfig command filtering for "Phys" doesn't indicate which is which.  The getmac command is the easiest to use since it only displays mac addresses and transport name but none of the other information.  It's best to have the ethernet disconnected so the transport name is listed as "Media disconnected" for easy identification.  If you don't have any virtual networks installed your wireless is the only other address listed.